# Do you set SameSite=None for the obps cookie?

Tags: wso2-identity-server

Do you set SameSite=None for the obps cookie?

Answer (score 0):

The SameSite attribute value sets as `None;Secure` for the `samlssoTokenId`, `commonAuthId` and `opbs` cookies[1][3].

Refer:

[1] https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.11.0/administer/samesite-attribute-support/#samesite-attribute-in-wso2-identity-server

[2] https://github.com/wso2/product-is/issues/10489

[3] https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-inbound-auth-oauth/pull/1314